# Ajax Control Toolkit custom Tab extender to close tabs client-side

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer, tabpanel, extender

I'm attempting to write an AJAX control extender that can modify an AJAX Control Toolkit `TabPanel` so that the `TabPanel`'s header has an image after the text that, when clicked, hides the tab header using client-side script (without a postback). I would also like to be able to specify an onClientClose function that is also called when a tab is closed.

I'm new to ASP control extenders, and so far I've followed the [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/creating-a-custom-ajax-control-toolkit-control-extender-cs"Creating a Custom AJAX Control Toolkit Control Extender") on the ASP.NET site for creating a custom extender. I've called my extender a `ClosableTabPanelExtender`, and my extender project builds. I set up a test web page like so:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server">
    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel0" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>Tab 0</HeaderTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate>Hello!</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>Tab 1</HeaderTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate>Goodbye!</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
<cc1:ClosableTabPanelExtender ID="ClosableTabPanelExtender1" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="TabPanel1" />
```

So far, I am getting the following error when I run the website:
`The TargetControlID of 'ClosableTabPanelExtender1' is not valid. A control with ID 'TabPanel1' could not be found.`
The error makes me think that a `TabPanel` can't be extended, so am I going to have to extend the `TabContainer` instead?

Apart from the error, I could use some direction, especially with the Behavior script. It is the most elusive part to me, though I know that it will likely house most of the functionality that I am trying to add. I'm also not sure how the other parts of the extender work together with it.

I have the Ajax Toolkit source code, and have looked through the source for the Tab controls, which I partially understand. I've also looked through several examples of control extenders, primarily [Matt Berseth's extenders](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/disablecontrolextender.html) and one from Dan Wahlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what I needed to do. For anyone who is interested in the solution:

- In order to extend the TabPanel control, I had to get around the error I posted by overriding the `OnResolveControlID` method in my extender's server code (`ClosableTabPanelExtender.cs`).

  ```
  protected override void OnResolveControlID(ResolveControlEventArgs e)
  {
      // Get a reference to the outermost TabContainer that contains the TabPanel being extended.
      TabContainer tabContainer = (TabContainer)base.FindControl(OuterTabPanelID);
      if (tabContainer != null)
      {
          // Check to see if any of the tabs are the control we are looking form.
          foreach (TabPanel tab in tabContainer.Tabs)
          {
              if (tab.ID == e.ControlID)
              {
                  e.Control = tab;
                  return;
              }
          }
          // If none of the tabs are what we are looking for, search the contents of each tab.
          foreach (TabPanel tab in tabContainer.Tabs)
          {
              Control ctrl = tab.FindControl(e.ControlID);
              if (ctrl != null)
                  return;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- As for the client-side Behavior script of the extender (and the interaction between the server and client code, the articles listed on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398782.aspx) are helpful and will save you a lot of trouble.